# AmazonConnect Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'state' of null] Callback failed

Tags: opencti, cti, softphone, amazon-connect

We have an Amazon Connect installation (v4.4) in our Salesforce org and it was working fine until this week when it started showing a 'Sorry to Interrupt' message on incoming calls.

I've disabled all custom scripts/components and still receive the issue.  This error only shows up for a select number of call center users and shows up at random for those users.

I have not been able to reproduce this issue in a sandbox.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

```
Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'state' of null]
Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.opencti.components.openCtiApiHandler.OpenCtiApiHandlerController/ACTION$getSearchUsingSoftphoneLayout
throws at https://dummy_org.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/AE898lCB2KpCUerBipCwXg/aura_prod.js:66:15. Caused by: Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'state' of null]

Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.opencti.components.openCtiApiHandler.OpenCtiApiHandlerController/ACTION$getSearchUsingSoftphoneLayout
Object.fireSearchRequest()@https://dummy_org.lightning.force.com/libraries/forceSearch/searchLibrary.event.js:4:244
Object.fireSearch()@https://dummy_org.lightning.force.com/libraries/forceSearch/searchLibrary.event.js:6:96
Object.navigateToSearchPage()@https://dummy_org.lightning.force.com/libraries/opencti/ctiLibrary.navigation.js:3:163
Object.searchAndScreenPopHandleInboundNavigation()@https://dummy_org.lightning.force.com/auraCmpDef?aura.app=markup://one:one&_au=xPMHjhRYKs3Pd1nCeZrBzQ&_ff=DESKTOP&_l=true&_l10n=en_US&_c=false&_style=-1244045752&_density=VIEW_ONE&_def=markup://opencti:openCtiApiHandler&_uid=LATEST-5:50:135
Object.searchAndScreenPopControllerCallback()@https://dummy_org.lightning.force.com/auraCmpDef?aura.app=markup://one:one&_au=xPMHjhRYKs3Pd1nCeZrBzQ&_ff=DESKTOP&_l=true&_l10n=en_US&_c=false&_style=-1244045752&_density=VIEW_ONE&_def=markup://opencti:openCtiApiHandler&_uid=LATEST-5:39:6
Object.<anonymous>()@https://dummy_org.lightning.force.com/auraCmpDef?aura.app=markup://one:one&_au=xPMHjhRYKs3Pd1nCeZrBzQ&_ff=DESKTOP&_l=true&_l10n=en_US&_c=false&_style=-1244045752&_density=VIEW_ONE&_def=markup://opencti:openCtiApiHandler&_uid=LATEST-5:24:154
```

Comment: As it's a managed package, I'd say that it's more a problem on Amazon's side nor Salesforce's. Have you tried to reach their support?

Comment: Yes, they haven't been able to come back with any solutions as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click here to see more about the issue. Seems a known issue happening recently

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002JRdpQAG

There is a workaround and my call centre agents are testing if the workaround is getting them away from error.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.